# apply function from methods to reverse string in paragraph in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Dears, I have tried to apply function to reverse string in paragraph text in vue.js,
I have created function to reverse words in methods called (reverseword) and added it

card using :rule="reverseword()",but it does not work. your support is highly appreciated
Code:

````
    <div class="post-box">
        <span class="post-viwes">{{viwes}}</span>
        <h3 class="post-title">{{title}}</h3>       
         <span class="post-date">{{date}}</span>
        <p class="post-content">{{content}}</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-sm-6 text-right">
              <span class="post-author">{{author}} </span>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-sm-6 text-right" :rules="reverseword()">
              <span class="post-category"  >{{category.toUpperCase()}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props:["viwes","title","date","content","author","category"],
    name:"posts",
      methods: {
        reverseWord: function () {
          this.category = this.category.split('').reverse().join('')
    }   
}};
</script>```
````

Comment: your question says `:rule="reverseword()"` ... your code says `:rules="reverseword()"` ... however, what do you expect the `rules` on the `div` to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your `reverseWord` method attempts to mutate a prop (`category`).
You can't mutate a prop, because the mutation would be overwritten by the first update from the parent.

If/when you do want/need to change a prop value, you have do it in the parent component which will then pass the change down to the child component, through the props binding.

Updating the parent from child can be done by

- either using [$emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event)
- or by using a store, external to both the child and the parent.

---

If, in fact, you don't want to mutate `category`, you just need to be able to use its reverse inside the template, create a `computed` property:

```
computed: {
  reversedCategory() {
    return this.category.split('').reverse().join('');
  }
}
```

Use it in template as you would use a normal property:

```
 <div class = "col-sm-6 text-right" :rules="reversedCategory">
   <span class="post-category"  >{{category.toUpperCase()}}</span>
 </div>
```

The `computed` is reactive. Meaning every time `category` changes, `reverseCategory` will update accordingly.